# Using WPF WebBrowser control to render web app built with D3.js framework

Tags: wpf, d3.js, webbrowser-control

I have a very simple web page that renders a graph using D3.js framework.
It works both on my local machine (with a web server) and on an actual remote web server - page loads without JS errors.
I want to create a standalone C# WPF app that renders that graph,
So I'm using the WebBrowser control to do that - but JS errors pop up:

First I get this message:

> "To help protect your security, your web browser has restricted this
>   file from showing active content that could access your computer.
>   Click here for more options"

Then after allowing, this error popup:

> "An error has accrued in the script on this page. 
>   Line: 3 
>   Char: 2133"
>   Error: "Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference"
>   code: 0 
>   URL: .../d3.min.js"

Few points:

1. Those messages\errors do not appear when loading the page from a browser(IE and Chrome)
2. I've tried building a WinForms app with WebBrowser control and to turn the "IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled" to true - the error message goes away, but the page does not render.
3. The D3.JS framework is contained to one file which seems to be obfuscated.

Any insights to why this happens or what could be done will be much appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the root of the problem and the solution.

The problem was, that by default WebBrowser controller loads IE8 engine which is not supported by D3.js framework.

The solution is to add a registry key that will force it to use IE9 engine as described here:
http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1720

Comment: You can find other `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` values [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation)